# How to use react components in blaze?

Tags: reactjs, meteor-blaze

I have made a `Header` component. Now I want to add the header component inside my blaze template but after adding it inside blaze template I cannot see any changes on my web page.

Code:

Header.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

const Header = () => {

    return(
        <div>
        <div>
                <h2>Hello World. I am header component</h2>
        </div>

        </div>

    )
}

export default Header;
```

header.html:

```
<template name="LeagueHeader">
{{#if isCordova}}
  {{> HeaderMobile }}
{{else}}
    <div>
        {{> React component=Header }}
    </div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Above code does not work why so ? I am not getting any errors. Do I need to add any helper function which returns `Header` react component ?

Comment: Have you seen the [React Components in Blaze](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#react-in-blaze) part of the documentation?

Comment: @Tholle Yes but in my case what else do I need to add ?

Comment: @stonerock what does your header.js look like? To answer the original question, yes you need to return the `Header` component in the helper function.

Comment: @theJuls I have not created any `Header.js` file ? What will Header.js contain in mycase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation that @Tholle [linked to you](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#react-in-blaze)

You do need to have a `header.js` file to go with `header.html`. This will contain the helper, which you need in order to render the component in your Blaze template.

The file should be in the same folder as `header.html` and should look like this:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './header.html';
import Header from './Header.jsx';

Template.LeagueHeader.helpers({
  header() {
    return Header;
  }
})
```

Comment: Do I need to import header.html which is blaze template inside header.js ?

Comment: Yes. You also want to import `Template`. I do highly suggest you give the documentation a thorough read.

Comment: No I don't want to import template so no need to import header.html right ?

Comment: Can you edit your answer is we need to add header.html or not ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Why not import it? Sure. I'll edit my answer, but please read the documentation, this is all covered there.

Comment: I am getting error saying component argument missing. https://imgur.com/a/x5rSRKk

Comment: What's in your component and in your template? You may want to update the OP with those.